# Deploying and reading static files on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, lucene

Due to limitations of the experimental Search API I've decided to use Apache Lucene for my fulltext search needs. I have looked at the AppEngine ports of Lucene but they do not suit my needs (ones using RAMIndex will not support the size of my index and ones using the datastore are too slow performance-wise), so I've tested out Lucene using my local filesystem and found that it works perfectly for me.

Now my problem is how to get it to work on AppEngine. We are not allowed to write to the filesystem, but that is fine because he index is created on my dev machine and is read-only on the server (periodically I will update the index and need to push the new index up). Reading from the filesystem is allowed so I figured that I would be able to bundle up my index along with my other static files and have access to it.

The problem that I've run up against is the AppEngine static file quotas (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime at the bottom of the page). My index is only around 750MB so I am fine on the "total files < 1GB" front, however some of my index files are several hundred MB and therefore would not be allowed on AppEngine due to the 32 MB max per file.

Is there any way to deploy and read static files larger than 32 MB on AppEngine? Or will I be stuck having to setup some other server (for instance Amazon) just to read my Lucene index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 750MB file, you must use BlobStore or Google Cloud Storage.

If you can change code for access static file in Lucene, you can use request to BlobStore or Cloud Storage to read file. But if static file is only option, you must split index into 32MB pieces.

If you change code for Lucene file access, you have limit of 32MB for each read request. So, file must be read in pieces.

Comment: Blobstore and Google Cloud Storage are not an option (without writing a massive library to integrate with Lucene with them). It looks like it is also impossible to split my indexes less than 32MB. Unfortunately it looks like there is no way to get this working on GAE and I have to find another place to host this portion of my app.